# Python - Stop a for loop after the key in a dictionary has been found

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I need the `for` loop to not continue looking through the dictionary once the `usernameMatch` bool value has been changed to `False`.

```
def username():
    usernameMatch = True

    while usernameMatch == True:
        print ('Username:')
        username = input()
        print ('checking username......\n')

        for key in usernameDictionary:
            if username == key:
                print('match')
            else:
                usernameMatch == False
```

Comment: You can use the `break` statement in the if statement

Comment: A `break` would do the trick. But please, go over the fundamentals of Python because this is one of the basic ones. You won't get too far without taking some basic training.

Comment: btw the while loop is superfluous. Also there are easier ways of checking if a variable is a key in. dict.

Answer (score 2):

As all the comments say, use the `break` statement:

```
for key in usernameDictionary:
    if username == key:
        print('match')
    else:
        usernameMatch == False
        break
```

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing the following:

```
def username():

usernameMatch = True

while usernameMatch == True:

    print ('Username:')
    username = input()
    print ('checking username......\n')

    if username in usernameDictionary:
        print("yes")
    else:
        usernameMatch = False
```